# rewriting .filter code i made

Tags: jquery, find

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $a = $('.post td span a'); 
$a.filter(':contains("TheGamer")').closest('td').removeClass('row1 row2').next('td').removeClass('row1 row2').closest('tr').addClass('manager'); 
 });
```

hey guys just wondering if you could help me rewrite this code.

It works for what it is written for but now I want to do something completly different!

Instead of :contains text string, I want to find the inline style and then do what it ask.

```
<span style="color:#0000ff;">TheGamer</span>
```

I'm not big in understand all the .find/.attr/.css()

So if someone could help me that would be fantastico!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var target = $('span[style]');
```

Will give you all `span`s that have a set attribute `style='...'`.

Comment: Ok so how would it be written? just not sure where to place it and how to define the add class/remove class. also I don't want any span[style] i just want '.post span a[color:#0000ff]')

Comment: @user1726062 AFAIK there's no appearance-based selectors. Best you can do is detect classes (`$('span.classnamehere')` or `$elem.hasClass('classnamehere')`.

Comment: hmm well gues that won't work for me then. Only way I could find this is by the exact hex code. I'll figure some way to make it work the way i need to, if i need to look for something else, maybe an image?? dunno. but do you know of a way to add another function if this is true, then addClass to .postbody?